# How to make circles repeat in the background of an element in full CSS?

Tags: html, css

I want to customize a slider like this:

[image: Slider]

So I was wondering if there was an easy CSS way of doing that, which would adapt to the width of the parent element. Or if I need to add circles in my html and set the color given the percentage.

Here are my two problems that I don't know how to do in full CSS:

- Make circles repeat in the background
- color only circles using some kind of overlay div that would have `background: @color`

Is any of that possible?

Thanks!

I don't want to use anything with javascript though, my webpages are heavy enough as is :p

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a repeated radial gradient to create dots like this:

[image: Dots]

1. Create a single circle with a radial gradient:

   ```
    radial-gradient(ellipse at center, #ffbdd7 0%, #ffbdd7 30%, transparent 30%)
   ```
2. Place the gradient into a `background` which is repeated on the x-axis with `background-repeat: repeat-x`
3. Center the background horizontally with `background-position`
4. Control the size of the circles with `background-size`

#### Example

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
div {
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, #ffbdd7 0%, #ffbdd7 30%, transparent 30%);
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-position: 5px center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

### Create a custom range slider input

[image: Range slider]

You can use `<input type="range">` and customise it. It's a little bit messy to work cross-browser.

#### Example

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
input[type=range] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, #ffbdd7 0%, #ffbdd7 30%, transparent 30%, transparent 100%) 5px center repeat-x;
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 50px;
  outline: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
/*Chrome*/
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  height: 27px;
  width: 15px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #ffffff 0%, #ffffff 39%, #ffbdd7 39%, #ffbdd7 61%, #ffffff 61%, #ffffff 100%) 0 no-repeat;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-size: 100% 17px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transition: box-shadow .3s;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)
}
/*Firefox*/
input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
  height: 27px;
  width: 15px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #ffffff 0%, #ffffff 39%, #ffbdd7 39%, #ffbdd7 61%, #ffffff 61%, #ffffff 100%) 0 no-repeat;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-size: 100% 17px;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
input[type=range]::-moz-range-track {
  background: none;
}
/*IE 11 and Edge*/
input[type=range]::-ms-track {
  color: transparent;
  background: none;
  border: none;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-thumb {
  height: 27px;
  width: 15px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #ffffff 0%, #ffffff 39%, #ffbdd7 39%, #ffbdd7 61%, #ffffff 61%, #ffffff 100%) 0 no-repeat;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-size: 100% 17px;
  border: none;
  margin-top: 3px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
input[type=range]::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: none;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="range">
```

A useful blog article on cross-browser range input styling can be [found over here](http://brennaobrien.com/blog/2014/05/style-input-type-range-in-every-browser.html).

Comment: I like this solution way better than my attempt!

Comment: Thanks I'll try that! @Le-roy your solution is great for non animated sliders, but if you animate it the circles just move with the handle so I'll try with this to see if it does the same. If it does I'll just put an image in the background :)

Comment: Yep this is actually better because it doesn't matter where the handle is, the dots/circles are always at the same position. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You could fudge it with a full-stop repeated within a `CSS` content attribute on the `:before` and `:after` selectors.

**Crude example:**
https://jsfiddle.net/xkueyxvb/

Comment: Ahahah, I like that very much! Thank you that's perfect!